# Use AssignUserId as variable in Apache MPM ITK

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache-2.2, web-server

I heard that the MPM-ITK module for Apache can change Apache server's behaviour to access some folder / file using the UID or GID from the default UID (`www-data`) into a given UID on the configuration.

For example:

```
<IfModule mpm_itk_module>
AssignUserId user group
</IfModule>
```

Is it possible to make the username and group a variable?

I want to make Apache access the `/home` folder as its owner. For example `/home/me` can only be accessed by the user `me`, while `/home/you` can only be accessed `you`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `mod_macro`.

Define one VirtualHost macro an use it with `Use`

```
<Macro Hosting $who>

    <Directory "/home/$who">
        allow from all
        Options +FollowSymLinks
    </Directory>

    <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName $who.domain.com
        AssignUserId $who $who
    </VirtualHost>
</Macro>

Use Hosting me
Use Hosting you
```

Answer (score 1):

From Apache 2.4 on, mpm-itk has the `AssignUserIDExpr` and `AssignGroupIDExpr` directives, which allows an Apache expression to be used in dynamically defining a user and group. In combination with mod-rewrite it will probably do what you want.

http://mpm-itk.sesse.net/

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried using `AssignUserId` per `Location` or `Directory` in Apache, but it does work for different virtual hosts, like so:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName my.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /home/me
    AssignUserID me me
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName your.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /home/you
    AssignUserID you you
</VirtualHost>
```